# Truncate all tables in postgres database

Tags: postgresql

In May 2010, Aaron and Henning both provided the code to register a function that when called later with a parameter for 'username' would truncate all the tables.  It worked fine with postgres on Windows 7.  Neither will work unfortunately for postgres 8.3 on Ubuntu.

```
An error has occurred:
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "$1"
LINE 1:   $1 
          ^
QUERY:    $1 
CONTEXT:  SQL statement in PL/PgSQL function "truncate_tables" near line 6
```

I have also tried simplifying the select statement to focus on the BEGIN For clause,
by removing the complicated WHERE clause I used in Windows.
Can you see the problem here?  Thanks.
Is it unable to pass or read the tablenames after they are retrieved?  Doesn't a problem with $1 mean it can't find its input?

```
DECLARE 
    stmt RECORD;  
    statements CURSOR FOR  
    SELECT tablename FROM pg_tables  
    WHERE  tablename !~* 'sql_*' and tablename !~* 'pg_*' and tablename !~* 'schema_*';  
BEGIN  
    FOR stmt IN statements LOOP  
        EXECUTE 'TRUNCATE TABLE ' || quote_ident(stmt.tablename) || ' CASCADE;';  
    END LOOP;  
END;
```

Comment: $1 does not appear in the quoted partial function, so you have cut out critical information.  Please provide the full function create;

Answer (score 3):

It appears that some of the function syntax changed between version 8.3 and 8.4. Try this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.truncate_tables(username IN VARCHAR) RETURNS void AS $$
DECLARE
    stmt RECORD;
BEGIN
    FOR stmt IN SELECT tablename FROM pg_tables
        WHERE tableowner = username AND schemaname = 'public' LOOP
        execute 'TRUNCATE TABLE public.' || quote_ident(stmt.tablename) ||' CASCADE;';
    END LOOP;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```